# additional case created via auto response bouncing to original case

Tags: email, email2case

We are running into an issue where a case created via email to case has an invalid return email. When the auto response email is sent, it is bounced back and creates an additional case.

What is the best course of action to prevent this additional case being created?

I know in the deliverability settings there is an option to disallow "Return bounced emails to sender", however we can not uncheck this because we use salesforce email services in other places where we need to be aware of bounced emails.

As far as I can tell there is nothing on the case that denotes it was created via a bounced email, and there is no universal response format for bounced emails so a trigger on the case object looking for "bounced" in the body or subject won't work 100%.

Open to any ideas that anyone might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only approach that I can think of is to write a Trigger on `Case.` From there, you need a scoring algorithm to detect if the inbound case was created via an email bounce. According to the documentation, [Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000089879&type=1) looks at  Origin, Subject, Sender and Body to detect looping, so maybe start with those parameters. [Here is some boiler plate](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232688&type=1) code from Salesforce on how to handle a similar situation

Comment: I came across that salesforce knowledge article. I love how the title talks about bounced emails, but provides no solution to it. I did notice that salesforce sets the web name to `Salesforce Bounce Forwarder` so I will be taking the trigger approach and looking at that.